# Array elements automatically created by default constructor?

Tags: c++

I have a class lets say `aClass`

```
class aClass
{
   public:
   int data;
   aClass(): data(-1) { //default constructor
   }
   aClass(int x): data(x) {  //int constructor
};
```

If I create an array like

```
aClass* arr=new aClass[10];
```

Question 1:
I was thinking no `aClass` object has been created since it is just a declaration of an array, but in a program that I tested it looks like `arr[0]` to `arr[9]` all points to a `aClass` object created by default constructor in its class? Because I had tested the program and the result is `a[0].data=-1` all the way to `a[9].data=-1`.

Question 2: if objects are created with their default constructor, how am I supposed to create an array that has objects created by int constructor? obviously I can't write code like

```
aClass* arr=new aClass(2015)[10];
```

Comment: Everything apart from some more advanced stuff is initialized to some degree in C++. For `new Type[size]`, it's default-initialization. It just happens that default-initialization for fundamental types like `int` is specified to be no initialization.

Comment: _"I was thinking no aClass object has been created since it is just a "declaration of an array"_ Well, yeah... an array of objects.

Answer (score 3):

> Quesntion 1: I was thinking no aClass object has been created since it is just a declaration of an array

You were thinking wrong. It's a declaration of a **pointer** which is initialized with the return value of `new aClass[10]` which **constructs** an array of 10 objects.

> but in a program that I tested it looks like arr[0] to arr[9] all points to a aClass object created by default constructor in its class?

Yes, your observation is correct.

> Question 2: if objects are created with their default constructor, how am I supposed to create an array that has objects created by int constructor?

Since c++11 you can use list initialization: `aClass *foo = new aClass[3]{1, 2, 3};` as chris pointed in a comment.

You may want to use std::vector instead. There is `std::vector::vector(size_type n, const value_type& val)` for constructing copies and since c++11: `std::vector::vector(initializer_list<value_type>)` for different values.

With static/automatic arrays aggregate initialization was possible even before c++11:

```
aClass foo[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Comment: `arr[0]` to `arr[9]` all **references** a aClass object... seems better

Comment: You can with dynamic arrays: `aClass *foo = new aClass[3]{1, 2, 3};`. Pretty sure only since C++11, though, and `std::vector` is a much better choice.

Comment: @chris Oh, cool. I didn't know that. Mind if I add that to the answer?

Comment: @user2079303, Go ahead. In general, if I want to add something, I just credit the commenter when introducing it, since asking is noise.

Comment: @Lingxi: "names" is better. There are no references here.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `aClass* arr=new aClass(2015)[10];` 
You could do `aClass *arr = new aClass[10]{2015, 2015/*etc*/};` if your compiler supports it.

In C++11, both of these mean the same thing.

```
aClass *arr = new aClass[10];
aClass *arr = new aClass[10]{};
```

Better alternative would be to use `std::vector` and avoid using raw pointers and instead use smart pointers ex. `std::unique_ptr`.

Example of this alternative could be:

```
int main()
{
    vector<unique_ptr<aClass>> vec;
    for (int i{0}; i != 10; ++i)
        vec.emplace_back(new aClass(2015));

    for (auto const& i : vec) // print data
        cout << i->data << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding question 1. The rules for [initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) are very rigid. Your array `new[]` expression creates an array of values. Those values must be initialized and by default they use [default initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization).

The answer to question 2 is that you can't do that with dynamic arrays. However, `std::vector` does provide a constructor that allows you to provide an object that will be copied to each of the contained elements. See [`explicit vector(size_type count, const T& value = T(), const Allocator& alloc = Allocator())`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

If you want each element in the collection to be different, then you must use a loop and assign the elements individually unless the size of the array is determined statically in which case you can use initializer expressions. If you want to avoid the initial default construction for dynamic containers, then you should not store the objects by value. You should use a container of pointers or better yet a container of smart pointers. Then you can use direct initialization for each object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create array of pointers if you want to create an array without creating the objects. For example, `aClass** arr = new aClass*[10];` creates an array of pointers. And when you want to create the actual objects, you need to do something like this: `arr[0] = new aClass(2015);`